# Geometric sampling problem in the Euclidean space in high dimensions

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, probability-distributions, algorithms, geometric-probability

Let $T$ be the triangle whose vertices are three given points $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}, \mathbf{z}\in\mathbb{R}^d$.

---

**Question**: What ***computationally efficient*** strategy can we use to sample a point $\mathbf{p}$ from $T$ with probability linearly proportional to $\|\mathbf{p}\|_2$?

Comment: @CaptainEmacs could you please provide me the *expected* time complexity for the *worst-case input triplet*, where the expectation is taken over the randomization of the sampling strategy? Thanks.

Comment: I saw from your conversation below that it's a deeper-seated question, apologies for the premature judgement. Some questions look really HW-like, I am slightly displeased when I find my students' questions online, so when I see something that might be someones HW, this triggers me a bit quicker than it should.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs no problem at all, I see the point. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't make any difference that $d\gg 1$. If $0<a<b<1$, $Q(a,b)=\|a\mathbf x+(b-a)\mathbf y+(1-b)\mathbf z\|_2^2=a^2\|\mathbf x\|^2+(b-a)^2\|\mathbb y\|^2+(1-b)^2\|\mathbf z\|^2+2a(b-a)\langle\mathbf x,\mathbf y\rangle+2(b-a)(1-b)\langle\mathbf x,\mathbf z\rangle$. That is, you should pick the point in the 2d simplex $\{(a,b)\colon 0<a<b<1\}$ with probability proportional to $\sqrt {Q(a,b)}$. This is then mapped to the point in your original triangle by $(a,b)\mapsto a\mathbf x+(b-a)\mathbf y+(1-b)\mathbf z$ (this mapping is linear, and so a proportion $t$ of the simplex maps to a proportion $t$ of the triangle).

Comment: OK, thank you Anthony. I removed from the question the constraint $d\gg 1$.

Comment: So I cannot tell you the most efficient way to sample this, but one simple possibility is not too bad in this two-dimensional case. First, to sample from the simplex, just pick two Uniform[0,1] random numbers and sort them into order (this is fast in any dimension). Second, the maximum value of $Q$ occurs at one of $Q(0,0)$, $Q(0,1)$ and $Q(1,1)$. Find it and rescale $Q$ by this value to obtain $\tilde Q$. Now sample a point in the simplex and retain it with probability $\sqrt{\tilde Q(a,b)}$ or otherwise just re-sample. As $\sqrt{\tilde Q}$ has integral far from 0, this is not so inefficient.

Comment: Thank you Anthony. I am wondering whether this rejection sampling techniques may lead to an expected ratio $\mathbb{E}\rho$ of rejections too large if $d\gg 1$... Is there any dependence of $\mathbb{E}\rho$ on $d$? How much could be $\mathbb{E}\rho$ for the worst-case input triplet?

Comment: If $d$ is the dimension of the ambient space, my answer shows it makes no difference: the distribution of the rejection probability is determined by the geometry of the two-dimensional simplex. If instead of a triangle, you wanted a high-dimensional object, that would be a different story. The rejection probability could scale very badly with the dimension of the object you are sampling over (but again, not the ambient dimension).

Comment: Here is an explicit estimate on the rejection probability. We may assume without loss of generality that $\|x\|\ge\max(\|y\|,\|z\|)$ and also that $\|x\|=1$ (so that $\tilde Q=Q$). Now you can integrate $Q$ over the simplex and check $\int Q=\frac 16(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2+\|z\|^2+\langle x,y\rangle+\langle x,z\rangle+\langle y,z\rangle)$ so $\int Q=\frac1{12}(\|x+y\|^2+\|x+z\|^2+\|y+z\|^2)$. Since $2x=(x+y)+(x+z)-(y+z)$, one of $\|x+y\|$,$\|x+z\|$, $\|y+z\|$ has norm at least $\frac 23$, so that $\int \tilde Q\ge \frac 1{27}$ and $\int \sqrt{\tilde Q}\ge \int \tilde Q\ge \frac1{27}$.

Comment: Thank you a lot Anthony, now I see the point. It is nice to have this constant bounded away from 0 for all $d$ in the method you proposed! Thank you also for the clarification details!